# Has this curiously simple result led to any non-trivial results?

Tags: nt.number-theory

I was flipping through an old algebra textbook (used during my time as an undergrad) and found an exercise: prove that for all positive integers $n$ and $a$, that $n | \phi(a^n - 1)$, where $\phi$ is the Euler totient function. The proof is deceivingly simple. First note that $\gcd(a, a^n - 1) = 1$ for $a > 1$ (the case $a = 1$ is trivial), and so $a^k \equiv 1 \pmod{a^n - 1}$ has a solution. In particular, it is plain that $n$ is the order of $a$ modulo $a^n - 1$ (no smaller $k$ will do just by size comparisons). Thus, $n | \phi(a^n - 1)$, by definition.

However, there is more than meets the eye with this simple exercise. For instance, one can prove that for any $n > 1$, that $n \nmid 2^n - 1$. The fact that the prime decomposition of $m$ and $\phi(m)$ are intimately related for $m$ not square-free makes this a curious relation.

This compelled me to believe that there is likely some other curious and not-so-easy to see facts that can be deduced by this exercise. Am I correct in this belief?

Thank you for any contributions.

Comment: Hi @StanleyYaoXiao.  Have you tried checking the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/)?  I tried a quick search but was unable to spot anything helpful - but I wish you the best of luck with this one!  =)

Comment: I would say that, if $m$ is squarefree, then the primes decompositions of $m$ and of $\phi(m)$ are pretty much unrelated. But the question strikes me as something of a fishing expedition.

Comment: If $a$ is a prime power, $\phi(a^n - 1)/n$ is the number of primitive polynomials of degree $n$ over $GF(a)$.  These sequences are in the OEIS for $a = 2,3,4,5,7,8,9$.

Comment: Actually, one can improve this result: $n\phi(a-1)$ divides $\phi(a^n-1)$. See here for instance (specifically, my comment): http://mathramble.wordpress.com/2012/04/19/a-divisibility-identity-for-eulers-totient-function/

Comment: Has this led to any surprising arithmetic results?

Comment: None that I know of.